# cross platform real time media streaming client

Tags: c++, angularjs, node.js, qt

I have a client-server solution with this behavior:
- Server side (C++) send frames in some standard format.
- Client side (C++) receives this frames, decodes and shows them.

I need to include this into a cross platform client with a friendly UI offering different streaming and some other basic stuff.

I wonder what is the better choice for do that. The best approach for me is having some webapp (Angular for instance) and export it into a desktop app using Electron. I'm not sure if this approach would work with c++.

Another option is using Qt.

I don't know if there are another possibility. I read something about nwjs.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Since your client is written is c++ Qt is the best option , but it has its own limitations of a limited resources.

In case you are willing to write the streaming client in js , then please use electron to convert your web app into cross platform app , since web applications have an infinite potential.

I can better answer if you can disclose the type of data transferred btwn the server and client , to check the feasibility of handling it through a web app.

Keep in mind that popular web apps use websockets to stream data to web apps and it's easy to extend a TCP server Into a Web socket server . ( Depends on the data transferred)

Comment: I don't familiar with the code yet, but data transferred are audio and video frames, foe example, compressed by h264 or something like that. The player has to get the frames and print them in the screen, another process has to send signals to the server when some keys are pressed (this is a custom protocol).

Answer (score 0):

Electron embed node thus one solution is to build your cross-platform UI with Electron and then you can call your c++ (that decodes frames) with node: https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html.